# JSON string deserialize changing object returned by API

Tags: json, string, object, type-conversion, converters

I am trying to deserialize a JSON String from an API, but I encounter an issue.

In fact, I created a class for every objects returned from the API, but if a same object (with the same id and content) appear many times in the string, the API transform the second apparition and more, on a simple string.

Here the precise example of my issue :

the first time appear like this =>

```
"object": {
        "typeObjet": "obj",
        "id": "01",
        "link": {
            "href": "https:obj.com",
            "rel": "sinone"
        }
      }
```

The second time appear like this in the same json string return =>

```
"object": "O1",
```

It is obvious that can't works if I try to deserialize a specific object who can be changed in the json string ! xD

So I tried a solution of course, before coming here and ask my question :

```
 public class ObjJsonConverter<T> : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader is null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.String:
                    var stringValue = reader.Value?.ToString();
                    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue) ? serializer.Deserialize<T>(new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(stringValue))) : null;

                case JsonToken.StartObject:
                    return serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);

                case JsonToken.StartArray:
                    return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);

                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seems to work all time.

The error is :

> Error converting value "01" to type 'Obj'. Path '[1].obj', line 1, position 11655.

What can I do for fix this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT :

OK I found a solution at my problem. APIs should never send the same object in another form. Instead of being a help, the API becomes a plague...

I put the solution here in case someone who has a similar problem goes through this :

```
        private Dictionary<KeyClass, ObjectDto> ExistingObjects = new Dictionary<KeyClass, ObjectDto>();


    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(AClass)
            || objectType == typeof(AnotherClass);
    }

    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var key = new KeyClass{ ObjectType = objectType };

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
        {
            key.Id = reader.Value.ToString();
            if (existingObjects.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                return existingObjects[key];
            }

            Log.Logger.Warning($"Object {objectType} with id {key.Id} not found");
            return null;
        }

        var obj = JObject.Load(reader).ToObject(objectType) as ObjectDto;
        key.Id = obj.Id;
        if (!existingObjects.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            existingObjects.Add(key, obj);
        }

        return obj;
    }
```